# magento 2 get store from block

Tags: magento2

Here is my block code and I am new in magento

All I need is shop name and title.
Basically its a magento 2 Webkul Marketplace extension which store data in 
marketplace_userdata table.

```
<?php
        /**
         * Webkul Software
         *
         * @category  Webkul
         * @package   Webkul_Mpsplitcart
         * @author    Webkul
         * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2016 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
         * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
         */
        namespace Webkul\Mpsplitcart\Block;

        use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
        use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
        use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

        /**
         * Mpsplitcart Block
         */
        class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart
        {
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
             */
            protected $httpContext;

            /**
             * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
             */
            protected $_cartHelper;
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
             */
            protected $_objectManager;

            /**
             * @var \Webkul\Mpsplitcart\Helper\Data
             */
            protected $_helper;

            /**
             * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
             */
            protected $checkoutSession;

            /**
             * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
             */
            protected $_cartModel;

            /**
             * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
             */
            protected $_priceHelper;

            /**
             * [__construct ]
             * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
             * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session                  $customerSession
             * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session                  $checkoutSession
             * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface        $objectManager
             * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url         $catalogUrl
             * @param \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart                    $cartHelper
             * @param \Webkul\Mpsplitcart\Helper\Data                  $helper
             * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart                     $cart
             * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data           $priceHelper
             * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context              $httpContext
             * @param array                                            $data
             */
            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl,
                \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,
                \Webkul\Mpsplitcart\Helper\Data $helper,
                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
                \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
                array $data = []
            ) {
                parent::__construct(
                    $context,
                    $customerSession,
                    $checkoutSession,
                    $catalogUrl,
                    $cartHelper,
                    $httpContext,
                    $data
                );
                $this->_cartHelper = $cartHelper;
                $this->_helper = $helper;
                $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
                $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
                $this->_cartModel = $cart;
                $this->_priceHelper = $priceHelper;
            }

            /**
             * [getSellerData get seller array in order to
             * show items at shopping cart accr. to sellers]
             *
             * @return [array]
             */
            public function getSellerData()
            {

                $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(10);
        echo     $name = $store->getName();
        // exit;
                // print "<pre>";
                // print_r( $this->_helper );
                // exit;


                $cart = $this->_cartModel->getQuote();
                $cartArray = [];
                foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {




                    if(!$item->hasParentItemId()){
                        $options = $item->getBuyRequest()->getData();

                        if (array_key_exists("mpassignproduct_id", $options)) {
                            $mpAssignId = $options["mpassignproduct_id"];


                            $sellerId = $this->_helper->getSellerIdFromMpassign(
                                $mpAssignId
                            );

                            // $storeName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
                            echo $this->_helper->getStoreName($sellerId);





                        } else {
                            $sellerId = $this->_helper->getSellerId($item->getProductId());
                        }

                        $price =  $item->getRowTotal();

                        $formattedPrice = $this->_priceHelper->currency(
                            $price,
                            true,
                            false
                        );
                        $cartArray[$sellerId][$item->getId()] = $formattedPrice;

                        if (!isset($cartArray[$sellerId]['total'])
                            || $cartArray[$sellerId]['total']==null
                        ) {
                            $cartArray[$sellerId]['total'] = $price;
                        } else {
                            $cartArray[$sellerId]['total'] += $price;
                        }

                        $formattedPrice = $this->_priceHelper->currency(
                            $cartArray[$sellerId]['total'],
                            true,
                            false
                        );
                        $cartArray[$sellerId]['formatted_total'] = $formattedPrice;

                        $cartArray[$sellerId]['seller_name'] = "Unknow";
                    }
                }
                return $cartArray;
            }

            /**
             * [getMpsplitcartEnable get splitcart is enable or not]
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function getMpsplitcartEnable()
            {
                return $this->_helper->checkMpsplitcartStatus();
            }

            /**
             * [getCartTotal used to get cart total]
             *
             * @return [string] [returns formatted total price]
             */
            public function getCartTotal()
            {
                $cart = $this->_cartModel->getQuote();
                $cartTotal = 0;
                foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    if(!$item->hasParentItemId()){
                        $sellerId=$this->_helper->getSellerId($item->getProductId());
                        $price =  $item->getProduct()->getQuoteItemRowTotal();

                        if (!$price) {
                            $price =  $item->getBaseRowTotal();
                        }

                        $cartTotal += $price;
                    }
                }
                $formattedPrice = $this->_priceHelper->currency(
                    $cartTotal,
                    true,
                    false
                );
                $cartTotal = $formattedPrice;

                return $cartTotal;
            }

            public function getSellerInfo($storeId)
            {
                // return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl();

                $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

                $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');


                return $storeManager->getStore(10)->getName();

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call store manager class again in __construct you can reuse $context

if you call store manager class inside __construct then it will through the error at the time of compile in production mode

so better approach is reuse the  $context as shown below

that is

```
public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .

            ) {
               .
               .
               .
               .
                $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In blocks, storeManager property is already initialized. Whenever you need the storeManager instance, use $this->__storeManager;

And in this case, in order to get store name, use this line:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getName();
```

Comment: Toan I am getting error 

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get store name in magento 2. Also follow this blog to get your answer. http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-get-base-url-and-media-url-and-static-url/

```
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager  
    ) {        
      $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function getStoreName()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
}

echo $this->getStoreName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this simple class how it works 
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-store-information-store-id-code-name-url-website-id/

```
<?php
namespace Chapagain\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Get website identifier
     *
     * @return string|int|null
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get current url for store
     *
     * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
     * @return string     
     */
    public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
    }

    /**
     * Check if store is active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isStoreActive()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I only need Seller Profile Information.